# All items of a UITableView disappear after deleting only one of them

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Looks a trivial task, however I cannot find what I am doing wrong. I have a table view with sections and I am able to delete 1 item, but when I try to delete more than one item all items disappear from the table.

It is important to mention here that the scenario works well if I delete only 1 row. Deleting one row does not impact the items of the UITableView.

When I click the edit button, every row is candidate for deletion. Code is

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

When I am deleting a row the code calls:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableArray *itemsOfGroup = [[table1 getItems] retain];
    int section = indexPath.section;
    section = section - 1;


    MyItem *deleteItem = (MyItem*)[[[sections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"SectionEntries"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [itemsOfGroup removeObject:deleteItem];

    [table1 setItems:[itemsOfGroup autorelease]];
    [[[sections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"SectionEntries"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];  
    [self createSections];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Is it possible to have a problem with my memory? (I think once the message "message sent to deallocated instance" appeared for an `NSArray` class)

Important to mention also that my items are not actually deleted from the data source. They only disappear from the table view.

Comment: Might be a good idea to look into ARC or how to use memory management before you go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you autoreleasing itemsOfGroup when you've just set the Items in table 1 to it? Should be a release call after the set, or better to use the self... mechanism with properties.  Check your memory allocations/deletions here. Are you throwing away all your content? Also, after your delete, what is your numberOfRowsInSection: and numberOfSections: returning?  check those.